# gorm scan error on column with type uuid[]

Tags: go, select, uuid

I have following models for a postgresql database:

```
SmallStruct struct {
    FirstUUID  uuid.UUID   `gorm:"column:first_id"`
    ListOfUUID []uuid.UUID `gorm:"column:list_of_id;type:uuid[]"`
}

BigStruct struct {
    SmallStruct
    ID         uuid.UUID  `gorm:"primarykey;column:id;type:uuid;default:gen_random_uuid()"`
    MyOwnField string `gorm:"column:my_own_field"`
}


func (BigStruct) TableName() string {
    return "my_schema.my_table"
}
```

And this is the table definition in database:

```
             Column             |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |            Default            
--------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------
 id                             | uuid                        |           | not null | my_schema.uuid_generate_v4()
 first_id                       | uuid                        |           | not null | 
 my_own_field                   | string                      |           | not null | 
 list_of_id                     | uuid[]                      |           |          |
```

I have following code to extract a piece of data from the table:

```
func GetData(id uuid.UUID) (*models.SmallStruct, error) {
    var data models.SmallStruct

    err := db.Model(&models.BigStruct{}).Where("first_id = ?", id).Find(&data).Error

    return &data, ParseError(err)
}
```

When I try to get data from this table using the code above, I get this error for field `list_of_id`:

```
sql: Scan error on column index 11, name "list_of_id": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type string into type *[]uuid.UUID
```

What would cause that?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. I should have used `pq.StringArray` from `"github.com/lib/pq"` library.

```
SmallStruct struct {
    FirstUUID  uuid.UUID      `gorm:"column:first_id"`
    ListOfUUID pq.StringArray `gorm:"column:list_of_id;type:uuid[]"`
}
```